# Post Firefox upgrade to version 60.3.0, not able to run automation tests

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

We are using robot framework for automation testing in our project. We were using Firefox version 47, gecko driver version 0.16.0 and selenium 3.14 and were able to run all the tests successfully.

Recently, IT team decided to upgrade Firefox to 60.3.0 and now automation is failing with error as:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities.
```

Tried using geckodriver versions 0.21, 0.22, 0.24 but in vain. Receiving same error.

Any help or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: @alexpulver While editing questions please don't add `<blockquotes>` to the error trace logs. Doing so debugging becomes difficult as the _error messages_ in the _error stack trace_  gets **word wrapped**.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities.
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

It is not clear from your question which combination of *Selenium*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox* combination produced the mentioned error. However as per best practices always follow the [GeckoDriver, Selenium and Firefox Browser compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html) below:

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

Comment: Thanks Debanjan for your reply. Below are the versions -       Firefox 0.60.3, selenium 3.14, geckdriver 0.16.0.  As per best practices, I tried using gecko driver 0.24.0, 0.22.0, 0.21.0 bus still same issue

Comment: @Samiksha Possibly you meant `Firefox 60.3` but then you have to use minimum `geckdriver 0.21.0`.

Comment: Yes, I meant 60.3, my bad. Anways, I tried with geckodriver 0.21.0 as well but I am receiving same error.